# Find $\frac{d}{dx}\left(f_1(x)f_2(x)\cdots f_n(x)\right)$.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f_k:(a,b)\to \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable and non-zero $(f_k(x)\neq0$ for all $a<x<b),\ k=1,\cdots,n$

Find $\frac{d}{dx}f_1(x)f_2(x)\cdots f_n(x)$.

Help appreciated!

Comment: See how it behaves when $n=2,3$ and then try induction.

Comment: Why did you double post?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint:**

1. $(f_1f_2)' = f_1'f_2 + f_1f_2'$
2. use induction

Comment: slap in the face obvious :-) (+1)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Note that
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\log(f)=\frac{\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}x}}{f}\quad\text{and}\quad \frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}x}=f\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\log(f)
$$
Then show that
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}(f_1f_2f_3\dots f_n)
&=(f_1f_2f_3\dots f_n)\left(\frac{\frac{\mathrm{d}f_1}{\mathrm{d}x}}{f_1}+\frac{\frac{\mathrm{d}f_2}{\mathrm{d}x}}{f_2}+\frac{\frac{\mathrm{d}f_3}{\mathrm{d}x}}{f_3}+\dots+\frac{\frac{\mathrm{d}f_n}{\mathrm{d}x}}{f_1}\right)
\end{align}
$$